# Concatenations of powers and their squares

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, arithmetic

At time of writing, my reputation is \$16,256\$. As I [noted in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55626072#55626072),

> Oh cool my rep is the concatenation of two powers of 2: 16,256
>
> Or even the concatenation of a power of 2 and its square, which is much more interesting

which then spawned a [CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/55626081#55626081) about checking if a number has this property.

---

Given an integer \$n > 0\$, considered a decimal integer, and a power \$r > 1\$, return two distinct values which determine whether \$n\$ can be expressed as the concatenation of a power of \$r\$ and its square or not. For example, \$n = 16256\$ and \$r = 2\$ returns true (the concatenation of \$2^4\$ and \$(2^4)^2\$), while \$n = 39\$ and \$r = 2\$ does not. Note however that \$n = 39\$, \$r = 3\$ *is* true. The power of \$r\$ may be \$0\$, meaning that \$n = 11\$ is true for all \$r\$

The power of \$r\$ will always come "before" its square, so \$n = 62525, r = 5\$ is false.

You will never get an input \$n\$ where its validity depends on ignoring leading \$0\$s or not (for example \$101\$ is true for all \$r\$ if ignoring leading \$0\$s and false otherwise). However, you may still get inputs with the digit \$0\$ in (e.g. \$n = 1024, r = 2\$) where leading \$0\$s have no bearing on the validity of \$n\$ being such a concatenation.

Input and output may be in [any accepted method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods) and this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
    n    r    1
   39    3    1
  525    5    1
  864    8    1
16256    2    1
   11    r    1
  416    7    0
   39    2    0
   15    5    0
 1024    4    0
62525    5    0
```

Feel free to suggest more test cases.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/63768/decimal-concatenation-of-squares), [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/173833/can-the-number-be-split-into-powers-of-2)

Comment: As is usual with my challenges, brownie points for beating my Jelly answer at 13 bytes

Comment: I didn't downvote but I guess someone tries to fix your reputation to 16256 ;-) +1 from me!

Comment: Missing `r` value in `11    r    1`? I guess it should be `1`.

Comment: @Adám That's supposed to demonstrate that its `1` for all `r`

Comment: Did you mean 62525 for that example?

Comment: @Neil I did, thanks!

Comment: Can we return `r` if true and 0 or -1 otherwise?

Comment: @user Yeah, that’s no problem

Comment: Can we return truthy/falsey instead of two distinct values?

Comment: @pxeger Those are two distinct values, so of course

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing no I mean like an empty or non-empty value. Not two distinct values but truth**y** and false**y**

Comment: @pxeger So long as there's no overlap between the possible outputs, you may choose any two sets of values to represent whether \$n\$ can be expressed in this way. That includes empty vs non-empty lists, truthy/falsey values etc.

Comment: Leading zeroes? Is 101 a valid COPAIS for all r?

Comment: @user253751 I'll say you don't have to worry about numbers which may or may not be valid depending on leading 0s, such as \$101\$, you'll never receive them as input

Comment: Is it required that we consider numbers as strings of *decimal* digits?  That's not specified anywhere in the problem, and it's easier (on a binary computer) to decompose numbers into power-of-2 bases, like base 8 or base 16. Or just base 2 directly, which most convenient input formats (function args) will already be in, and which can be squared directly after a bitfield extract.  So if you mean decimal, please say decimal somewhere in the question, unless non-decimal is listed as a standard loophole for digit problems on meta or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm not aware of any such standard loophole, and yes, the input should be *considered* decimal (I say "considered" because input as unary for example is perfectly acceptable), I'll edit that into the question

Answer (score 9):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 21 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319) ([SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS))

Anonymous infix lambda, taking \$r\$ as left argument and \$n\$ as right argument. Requires `⎕IO←0` (zero-based indexing).

```apl
{⍵∊(⊢⍎⍤,⍥⍕¨×⍨)⍺*⍳⌊⍟⍵}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/qG@qp/@jtgkG/6sf9W591NGl8ahr0aPevke9S3Qe9S591Dv10IrD0x/1rtB81LtL61Hv5kc9XY965wPV1v5PA@oDKe1qftS75lHvlkPrjR@1TQSaGBzkDCRDPDyD/6sbWqlzGSukKQCBsSWXKZhlamTKZQFmWZiZcBkBWYZmRqZmXIYQdYaGYDEIyxjOUjcAGmUO5poYmsGUwA1VMDTlMgGxDA2MTMBihkZAiwA) (Dyalog Extended as polyfill for version 18.0)

`{`…`}` "dfn", `⍺` is \$r\$ and `⍵` is \$n\$:

`⍟⍵` natural log of \$n\$ (to avoid overflow)

`⌊` round that down

`⍳` **ɩ**ntegers zero through one less than that

`⍺*` raise \$r\$ to those powers

`(`…`)` apply the following monadic function to that:

`×⍨` multiply those with themselves (i.e. square them)

`⊢`…`¨` for each unmodified argument and its corresponding square:

`⍥⍕`… stringify the argument and its square before

`⍤,` concatenating them, and then

`⍎` evaluating the result

`⍵∊` is the original argument a member of that?

Answer (score 8):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

```
ÝmεDn«}¹å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8Nzcc1td8g6trj208/DS//8NDQwMQBgIuAwNAA) This is a *little* inefficient, so don't try the larger falsey test cases.

**Commented:**

```
           # implicit input, n first, r second
Ý          # inclusive range from 0 to n
 m         # raise r to all of these powers
  ε   }    # map over the powers ...
   D       #   duplicate power
    n      #   square it
     «     #   and concatenate
       ¹   # push the first input (n)
        å  # is this in the list?
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>63</s> \$\cdots\$ <s>56</s></sup> 54 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [ovs](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/64121/ovs)!!!
Saved a byte porting [Arnauld](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58563/arnauld)'s golf of [Shaggy](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58974/shaggy)'s [JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211509/9481)!!!
Saved 2 bytes thanks to [pxeger](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/97857/pxeger)!!!

```python
f=lambda n,r,p=1:p>n or(n-int(f'{p}{p*p}'))*f(n,r,r*p)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDRbsMgDEXf8xV@C45cqRBIu0j0R7Y9tFuiVeoAESZ1Qnx7RlA0JTz5HtnY97rf8GVNO8@jfly/b59XMOTJad67iwHrmTncTWBjHV2KrnGpRmxGtjT5xuEchilMoIFVkB9j7Qu1SBxp1UooUltw7iSdt4B3QnUkdojvP5G8oxPS8R/kLWKreVmy0UchSe6IWC9ZEFZPzeq3H3GSHzWVgrc1VqP1EGiAu4Hiqy/D2Ws2GEq9WDU2QEkAC3J@Dcj0KhFEn@BwgTgliM/Xm7UPNqHWw3tObv4D)

Returns a falsey if \$n\$  can be expressed as the concatenation of a power of \$r\$ and its square or truthy otherwise.

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##VZDBbsMgDIbveQrfgiNXKgTSLhJ9kW2Hdku0Sh0gwqROiGfPCIqmhJP/T4D92f2GL2vaeR714/p9@7yCIU9O895dDFjPzOFuAhvr6FJ0jUs1YjOy5ZJvHM5hmMIEGlgF@TDWvlCLdERasxKK1BacO0nnLeCdUB2JHeL7TyTv6ITE/0HuIraZlyabfBSS5I6IdZIFYfXUrH77ESf5UVMpeFtjNVoPgQa4GyhefXmcXbNgKPWiWuyxROfX5ZheJYLoExwuEKcE8fl6s/bBJtR6eM9bm/8A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @pxeger Nice one with the multiplication beats logical `and` again - thanks! :D

Answer (score 6):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

Takes `r` as input and `n` as output. Unifies if truthy, otherwise fails.

```
;A^gj^₂ᵗc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFSu9qhtw6OmpodbOx51LFcqKSpN1VN6uKvzUccKpbTEnGIIr/bh1gn/rR3j0rPiwGqnJ///Hx1trKNgbBmrE22qo2BqZApkWOgoWJiZABlGOgqGZkamZkAmUJGhIZA211EwMTSDyMF0GYI0mQBpAyMTiAhQE9CkWAA)

#### How it works

```
;A^gj^₂ᵗc with implicit r as input
;A^       r^some number
   gj     [r^some number, r^some number]
     ^₂ᵗ  [r^some number, r^some number^2]
        c concatenated is the output n
```

Answer (score 6):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + pryr, <s>43</s> 39 bytes

*Edit: -4 bytes thanks to pajonk*

Or **[R](https://www.r-project.org/), [43 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc7RCsIgFIDh@z2F0I3CCfRMbUW@yobIgt0chzqip7cIIhjz@uOHP9UlTyFS8GVa43NOrj42CmWJxAmS8PTi5Nzqc5klz/dzGrm8kYA8ohD7mPdX6AVjJ6a6PRk0YBo2WA1Dw5RFYwFbqkBJ2UCtLFy@JruDU2yQ@o0ekEQNuoGfUfyn9Q0)**

```r
pryr::f(any(n==paste0(s<-r^(0:n),s^2)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5BCoMwEEDRvacIdJPAFDJjktrQXEUJYqGbKIkgnj4thVIQZ/348HN9lWGc0xjXYZm3KYe65D17/5Qx7TKFsMSyTlqWxzX3UvukoPSklDqGsr1Dq4S4CGyOZMmCZaxzBjrG0JF1QJwioNYMGnRw@5puTk6JIfyNnpAmA4bBzyj90/oG)

A nice function that is naturally short thanks to [R](https://www.r-project.org/)'s vectorization.

`s<-r^(0:n)` generates a vector of all powers-of-`r` from 0..`n` (the `<-` here is an [R](https://www.r-project.org/) assignment operator, similar to `=`),

`paste0(s,s^2)` generates a character vector of all these powers `paste`d onto their squares (the `0` in `paste0` instructs the function not to use a space in the concatenation),

`any(n==...)` finally checks to see whether `n` is equal to any of the elements of the vector, conveniently coercing `n` into character form to do this.

`pryr::f(...)` is a shorter way to express `function(n,r)` (from the `pryr` library), that 'guesses' the arguments using the body of the function definition (presumably by the order-of-appearance of unassigned variables: I can't actually find any explanation in [the manual page](https://rdrr.io/cran/pryr/man/f.html), but anyway it seems to work...!).

Comment: With `pryr` package installed you can get 4 bytes less: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc5BCoMwEEDRvacIdJPAFDJjktrQXEUJYqGbKIkgnj4thVIQZ/348HN9lWGc0xjXYZm3KYe65D17/5Qx7TKFsMSyTlqWxzX3UvukoPSklDqGsr1Dq4S4CGyOZMmCZaxzBjrG0JF1QJwioNYMGnRw@5puTk6JIfyNnpAmA4bBzyj90/oG "R – Try It Online")

Comment: Thanks! I was kind-of aware that ```pryr::f``` was a 1-byte shorter than ```function```, but I never realized how cleverly its 'argument guessing' could save the bytes of the arguments, too! Yet again, I'm accidentally learning something useful by golfing...

Comment: @pajonk that does change the language of the answer from "R" to "R + pryr" according to the way we distinguish languages

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>47</s> <s>44</s> 38 bytes

```javascript
n=>g=(r,x=1)=>x<n&&[x]+x*x==n|g(r,x*r)
```

-6 bytes thanks to Arnauld.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fc7PCoJAEIDxu08xJ5mxPzq6awaNLxIdxFQK2Q2N2EPvvhUFQWXnH3x8x@pSjfVwOJ0Xxu4b34o3UnaCw9wJk5RuY8Jw63YzFzkRc@0eEg3ka2tG2zfL3nbYIgBka8KMCOIYOPhUnWpCPaVFrgiLKQXmP2XFOeHqqUnw8yqdVH5ffSkn6f1KvdTfAA)

Comment: [38 bytes](https://tio.run/##fc7PCoJAEIDxu08xJ5mxPzq6awaNLxIdxFQK2Q2N2EPvvhUFQWXnH3x8x@pSjfVwOJ0Xxu4b34o3UnaCw9wJk5RuY8Jw63YzFzkRc@0eEg3ka2tG2zfL3nbYIgBka8KMCOIYOPhUnWpCPaVFrgiLKQXmP2XFOeHqqUnw8yqdVH5ffSkn6f1KvdTfAA)

Comment: Nice one, thanks, @Arnauld. Been a good while since I golfed drunk in JS!

Answer (score 3):

## Javascript (V8), <s>63</s> <s>60</s> <s>59</s> <s>53</s> <s>51</s> 43 bytes

*-3 from Neil*

*-2 and -8 from Shaggy*

```js
n=>r=>[...n+n].some((_,i)=>[p=r**i]+p*p==n)
```

Takes input via currying: `f("16256")(2)`. Works quickly and for all values within the safe integer limit (\$2^{52}-1\$). Returns `true` or `false`.

#### Old

```js
n=>r=>[...n+n].map((a,i)=>[s=r**i]+s*s).indexOf(n)
```

```js
n=>r=>[...Array(+n)].map((a,i)=>""+(p=r**i)+p*p).indexOf(n)
```

Comment: This outputs a consistent truthy value for `false` and either a truthy or falsey value for `true`. You may want to check if that's acceptable.

Comment: @Shaggy It always gives `-1` for `false`, and any nonzero number otherwise. I thought that's acceptable but I'll go check. (Either way, it's just two more bytes for a consistent truthy/falsy)

Comment: Just one more byte, because you can use `includes`.

Comment: `r**(i*2)` saves a byte, I think? Also, does `[...Array(+n)]` work instead of using `fill`?

Comment: @RedwolfPrograms, it returns `0` in the case of `n=11, r=1`.

Comment: @Neil Consistent/non-consistent seems to be an allowed method for output in [tag:decision-problem]s, so the extra byte isn't needed. Also yes your two golfs will work, thanks!

Comment: @Shaggy Oh, sorry, meant to say "nonnegative". That makes it fall under the consistent/non-consistent option for output in [tag:decision-problem]s.

Comment: Ah, looks like I was hung up on phrasing; that works for me now. Think you might be able to save a few bytes with `n=>r=>[...n+n].map((a,i)=>[s=r**i]+s*s).indexOf(n)`.

Comment: @Shaggy Never would have thought of that! Really clever way to get a string.

Comment: You can get down to 43 by using `some` instead of `map` & `indexOf` and checking for equality with `n` in the callback.

Answer (score 3):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-x`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 11 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ÆVpXÃ£¥X+²s
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LXg&code=xlZwWMOjpVgrsnM&input=MzkKMw)

```
ÆVpXÃ£¥X+²s     :Implicit input of integers U=n and V=r
Æ               :Map each X in the range [0,U)
 VpX            :  Raise V to the power of X
    Ã           :End map
     £          :Map each X
      ¥         :  Test U for equality with
       X+       :  X appended with
         ²      :  X squared
          s     :  Converted to a string
                :Implicit output of sum of resulting array
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 52 bytes

```
#^2+10^IntegerLength[#^2]#&[#2^0~Range~#]~MemberQ~#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc07C4MwEMDx3U9xEHBphiQ@aoeCS4dCC32MIUIq52MwBckm5qunoYitt/3uDv6Dth0O2va19s3Rk0rsOKvOxmKL4wVNazsZlorEkoiKuYc2LTqi3BWHF453R2J/G3tjZVOWp7p7S6JU7J61Nm6KIMwEkBwoJDNdmImMQrayyFMKxUrOKQDfUmwoWODilOcU9uv5W/p9A/8vcSZCKZ2j2fsP)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
function($n,$r){while($n>$b=($a=$r**$x++).$a*$a);return$n==$b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDdSsNAEIXv9ykOZSA/XSRJk1iNa@mFolCw0MsYShoTUpFNTFIUxGePkxo0N8ueM3Pmm926rPubVV3WQlCXt10LhVgIIMbiSmIh4SKRZx14gUQwMZahL7GcGG7oBaGEN7VcFhJwWZ8N3@WOSwlnbBgoHHD@Ar@Qf@14TPEnDkPGTZxEiCTizQvVFyeddcdKm6QlNdbXR3l8y1nc0kGZlCpqbJs@53PrglKbUitq8u7UaNJK0SH67iNRVE2eZqWJ8SPSlm@wmJlnZYXXttL7XGfVC4/tLInZczeToHdFxZCJ@UV8ugkmNSg1lLwEKxjb9W5n4BrG/fpxY0hsH7b7u6dN1P8A)

Or... put another way...

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
function($n,$r){while(0<$b=$n<=>($a=$r**$x++).$a*$a);return$b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBda8IwFIbv8yveyYG2ehhttM6tZuLFhgNhgpeuSO1S6hhp11Y2GPvtXdR99Cbkfc4bnkPKvGynszIvhaBG100NhY0QwAbDa8aQESDmUw5lyAg7YDIeMSYdEIxlOGbILgpsYJzBiYwCW7li@L@Vo0d2cnDW/GdfWs@oQ6xG/pWEiCO7fKba7GDSZl8YlwxT5X2@5/tX7fpT2ikyU3XrUqKo6vfpYzDwLinpU@JFlW4OlaFd9NVGIisqnaS5i5@/SGp7g2elOs0LvNSF2WqTFs/apcZj9J6aHoPeFGXHNxs/ZnsGMTozXKjjSMaYwVnN12sHN3Du5w9Lh7FarLZ3j8uo/QY)

Can't seem to get away from this number...

#### [PHP](https://php.net/), 63 bytes

```php
function($n,$r){while($n>$a=$r**$x.$r**($x++*2));return$n==$a;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBRa4MwFIXf8ysOJaC2YWiqrpvLSh82VihM6KOTIi5ix4hOLSuM/XZ37WTzJck59558N6nLur9b12XNGO9027VQSBgDEixvBJYCHlJx0YEMBIKJsQp9gdXE8EIZhAJyankkBOCRvhi@Rx3XAu7YMFAo4P4FfiH/2pVE8ScOQcZJ3JSxNKLJC9UXJ5N3x8rY3AjeOF@f5fFdk7jnmeLNfM7PV8Nm8/NiMZeOEzW6OzWGG6V4Fn33ESuqRmd5aWP8iKylExxi6rys8NZW5qBNXr3StZ0jMHvpZgL8Q/FiyCT0Ilq9FJMalBpKMsUaVrzZ7y3cwnrcbHeWQPwUHx6ed1H/Aw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>72</s> 70 bytes

```rust
|n,r|(0..n).any(|i|format!("{}{}",r.pow(i),r.pow(2*i))==n.to_string())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pU7LTsMwELznK5ac7MpYEEQPLumBA7@BAnGQVWdt@aG0SvLtwY6gjcSRvezszuzMuujDEr0EH1ohlBFi9FJ3DKyTOrZSiN18KIoOoW8UEgpjAam0DPlCIdSQj1ZM6OEPuXauzedpy/YxgFYo/U2Rpyy5alBAfKqSYKU4ynMglEccXGO3IDjVp2Yb5@Vmfwtz/zW6OnUCXs35pb0gvCFJpiw7U7g/wocx@pgyEi8EyoEsEzI3kQfOkfIGL2RSU2dc34Q7Uo7zOJfMcWsGougPqHaK0rpGHsy7T8/gF6F0ydm/P9i0DBpXg5JBR5CBo4mdl8d99bwvqqz6Bg)

A port of [ovs's 05AB1E answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211507/85922).  Thanks to ovs for helping save 2 bytes!

Answer (score 2):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 96 bytes

```
	N =INPUT
	R =INPUT
N	Z =R ^ X
	Y =EQ(N,Z Z ^ 2) 1	:S(O)
	X =LE(Z,N) X + 1	:S(N)
O	OUTPUT =Y
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K87LT8rPMfn/n9NPwdbTLyA0hIszCMby44xSsA1SiFOI4OKMVLB1DdTw04lSiAIKGGkqGHJaBWv4a3JxRijY@rhqROn4aSpEKGhDxP00ufw5/UNDgKYo2EZyufq5/P9vYWbCZQwA)

Prints 1 for Truthy, and an empty line for Falsey.

```
	N =INPUT			;* Input n
	R =INPUT			;* input R
N	Z =R ^ X			;* set Z = R^X (X starts as "" or 0)
	Y =EQ(N,Z Z ^ 2) 1	:S(O)	;* If N = Z concatenated to Z^2, set Y = 1 and goto O
	X =LE(Z,N) X + 1	:S(N)	;* If Z <= N, increment X and goto N, else:
O	OUTPUT =Y			;* print Y, which is '' unless N == Z Z^2
END
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 11 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
r#mÆ‼░²░+l╧
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/79IOfdw26OGPY@mTTy0CUho5zyauvz/f0NDBSMuIGFoACYNuYwtFYy5TI1MFUy5LMxMFCy4DEFMoKgRl4mhmYI5l6GBkYmCCQA) (The two test cases with the largest \$n\$ are timing out.)

**Explanation**

```python
r            # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input `n`)
 #           # Take (implicit) input `r` to the power of each value in this list
  m          # Map over this list,
   Æ         # Using the following five commands:
    ‼        #  Apply the following two commands on the stack separately:
     ░       #   Convert the value to a string
      ²      #   Square the value
       ░     #  Convert the squared value to a string a well
        +    #  Concatenate the two strings together
         l   # After the map: push the first input `r` as string
          ╧  # And check if this string is in the list
             # (after which the entire stack joined together is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
Ḷ*@ż²$Vi⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1aDkf3HNqkEpb5qHHH/8PLj8191LQm8v//aGNLHeNYnWhTI1MdUyBtYWaiYwGkDQ11LC0tgQwTQzMdcyANVGcEEocoMzQwMtExiQUA)

*-1 thanks to Jonathan Allan*

Elided the two larger test cases for the sake of being able to run.

Adapted from my own answer to the CMC. I've also attempted to adapt one of HyperNeutrino's cleverer answers, but it comes out to the same length on account of needing `Ḷ` to handle the `[11, r]`:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ḶżḤ$*@Vi⁸
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjm1H9zzcsURFyyEs81Hjjv@Hlx@b@6hpTeT//9HGljrGsTrRpkamOqZA2sLMRMcCSBsa6lhaWgIZJoZmOuZAGqjOCCQOUWZoYGSiYxILAA)

I save on an `@` and an `⁸` by reversing the arguments, but then it takes 2 bytes to handle an exponent of 0, taking it right back up to <s>10</s> 9:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
*Ɱ;1ż²$Vi
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/r0cZ11oZH9xzapBKW@f/wcodjcx81rYn8/z/a2FLHOFYn2tTIVMcUSFuYmehYAGlDQx1LS0sgw8TQTMccSAPVGYHEIcoMDYxMdExiAQ)

Comment: Nice, I didn't think of `V`, using that I now finally have a 9 (wasn't going to post until I had a 10 since I was sure 10 must be possible).

Comment: Ah I didn't notice at first, but your second one can be golfed to 9 too `;Ḥ$€` -> `żḤ$` :)

Comment: Funnily enough, that's something HyperNeutrino already used in a different one of his CMC answers--took me this long to figure out why! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

Uses the evaluation (`V`) trick from [Unrelated String's](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/85334/unrelated-string) [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/211540/53748) - go give an upvote!

```
*⁹ŻżḤ$¤Vċ
```

A dyadic Link accepting an integer \$r>1\$ on the left and an integer \$n>0\$ on the right which yields `1` if \$n\$ can be expressed as the concatenation of a power of \$r\$ and its square, or `0` if not.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9qZWxsef//KuKBucW7xbzhuKQkwqRWxIv///8z/zk4MQ)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/rUePOo7uP7nm4Y4nKoSVhR7r/H16u/6hpzf//0dHGOgrGlrE6CtGmOgqmRqYgloWOgoWZCYhlpKNgaAhiGMMYJjCGuY6CiaEZVBHcBENTmCIDI5PYWAA) (large \$n\$ excluded due to speed).

#### How?

```
*⁹ŻżḤ$¤Vċ - Link: r; n
      ¤   - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
 ⁹        -   chain's right argument, n
  Ż       -   zero-range -> [0,1,2,...,n]
     $    -   last two links as a monad:
    Ḥ     -     double -> [0,2,4,...,2n]
   ż      -     zip -> [[0,0],[1,2],[2,4],...,[n,2n]]
*         - (r) exponentiate (that) (vectorises)
       V  - evaluate (e.g. [9,81] -> 981) (vectorises)
        ċ - count occurrences (of n)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Rockstar](https://codewithrockstar.com/), 129 bytes

```
listen to N
listen to R
X's0
O's0
while N-X
let X be+1
P's1
Y's0
while X-Y
let P be*R-0
let Y be+1

let O be+P+""+P*P is N

say O
```

[Try it here](https://codewithrockstar.com/online) (Code will need to be pasted in, with `n` on the first line of input and `r` on the second)